# How to use multiple GPU in chainer.training.extensions.Evaluator?

Tags: chainer

because my train model is on multiple GPU, during training , I use trainer.extend to validate my model every epoch, But chainer.training.extensions.Evaluator has only one device argument, but my model network parameter is on 2 GPUs. how to validate in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The `device` argument of `Evaluator` indicates to which device the input data should be put. It does nothing about model parameters.

If your model needs the input data loaded to multiple GPUs as well, `Evaluator` does not support such case directly so you have to customize it. The easiest way is setting a custom converter function (which is responsible on copying the data to appropriate devices). See the document of `Evaluator` for the details of `converter`. https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.training.extensions.Evaluator.html

Comment: Do you mean the model parameter and data can be on two different GPU? then how can they to calculate together in this situation?(for example Wx + b but W and x are on 2 different GPU)?

Comment: I can't fully understand this

Comment: In that case, you have to manually send x to the GPU on which W exist.